# How can I quickly add a photo to an album in Photos app?

Tags: photos

I'm reviewing some photos I've taken in the photos app on a Mac. I'd like to put some of them into an album. However, it seems that to do this, for every photo I want to add, I have to click the '+' button and select "Album", which then pops up a modal dialogue where I have to select the name of the album from yet another drop-down, then click OK. There must be a quicker way than this. (Right?) What is it?

By the way: I know that I can select several thumbnails at once using the CMD key, but the problem is my eyesight is really poor (hence squinting at thumbnails gives me a headache), and in any case I want to check the photos are sharp before I add them to the album. So I'm looking for a quick way to add the photo to an album from looking at the photo itself, not from the thumbnails page. If it can be done by keyboard shortcuts, that would be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about the Photos app on Mac.

One option based on your description is to change the size of your thumbnail images so they're large enough to view the quality of images without having to manually open them up one by one. To change the thumbnail size drag the slider near the top left of the Photos app window.

Once you've got the size right, you can select multiple images (using the <kbd>Command</kbd> key) and then drag them across to the album you want. Of course, this assumes you've already created the album.

Another option, once you've selected the images you want, is to then go to File > New Album (or just use the <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> keyboard shortcut) and this will automatically create a new album including all the photos you had selected.

If you're interested in the full list of keyboard shortcuts for the Photos app, just go to Help > Keyboard Shortcuts. This will give you quick access to a list of keyboard shortcuts as well as Magic Mouse or trackpad gestures.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I already have the thumbnails at their maximum size, which is about 1/4 of the width of my screen, minus a bit because of the white gaps in between them. This is big enough to identify the largest objects in the photos, but not big enough to easily pick out detail with my eyesight, and certainly too small to check if they're in focus. As per the question, I'm looking for a way to add photos to an album *from looking at the photos themselves*, not from the thumbnail view.